# Improve the insertion rate of mongo sharded cluster

Tags: performance, mongodb, nosql

I can't disable the write concern while i mongorestore with .bson file. It totally damages the insertion rate (insert/sec).

This is my sharding status.

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
sharding version: {
"_id" : 1,
"version" : 4,
"minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
"currentVersion" : 5,
"clusterId" : ObjectId("546bd498f0531e27d40544b2")
} shards: { "_id" : "shard2", "host" : "shard2/hadoop5.xx.com:27018" } databases: { "_id" : "admin", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "config" } { "_id" : "deneme6", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "shard2" } { "_id" : "seref", "partitioned" : true, "primary" : "shard2" }
```

This is my shard. I already changed the property of getLastErrorDefaults w:0 for disable write concern.

```
shard2:PRIMARY> show tables; me oplog.rs startup_log system.indexes system.replset          shard2:PRIMARY> db.me.find() { "_id" : ObjectId("546bd2869e14c01f13708886"), "host" : "hadoop5.xx.com" } 
shard2:PRIMARY> db.system.replset.find() { "_id" : "shard2", "version" : 2, "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "hadoop5.xx.com:27018" } ], "settings" : { "getLastErrorDefaults" : { "w" : 0 } } } 
shard2:PRIMARY>
```

This is my mongorestore command which load data via query router ( mongos )

```
mongorestore --db seref --collection can11 --noobjcheck --w 0 --noIndexRestore --host       10.21.12.21 --port 27017 /tmp/iabc_kwd.bson
```

When i try to mongorestore on sharded cluster via mongos the insertion rate is 300k  byte / sec , when i try to mongorestore on single mongodb the insertion rate is 12m  /sec.

How can i speed up the insertion rate of restoring mongodb sharded cluster?

---

```
-- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("546ca29960e36f8983130015")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "hadoop5:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "hadoop6:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "hadoop4:27017" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "seref",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "abc",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
    {  "_id" : "mahmut",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0002" }
    {  "_id" : "incee",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0002" }
        incee.onur
            shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
            chunks:
                shard0000   1
                shard0002   501
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

All shards computer have 8 GB RAM , and they have 1.3 TB HDD.

Comment: There is some information missing: what is your shard key? Please edit accordingly. the output of db.status() on the respective database would be helpful, too. And please give the dimensions in terms of RAM, network bandwidth and type of Mass storage.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i added the information of shard cluster

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem (from what I can see)

From what I can see from your output, you have a monotonically increasing shard key like `ObjectId` or a `Date` or something similar.

MongoDB sharding is done with key ranges over the selected shard key. Put simply, it works like "`shard0000` is supposed to hold the rang from `-infinity to $i`, `shard0001` the keys from `$h to $p` and `shard0002` from `$q to infinity`. With a monotonically increasing shard key, every new value will be bigger than the last one inserted, heading to infinity, so the shard which will be used is *always* `shard0002`, instead of the writes being balanced to all shards.

So all of the write operations seem to hit `shard0002` with individual chunks being migrated to the other shards. The necessary chunk migrations together with added network latency and a lot of metadata updates going on, it may well be that you have a poor write performance.

#### The solution

Really bad news: you can't change the shard key once it is set. You basically have to create  new sharded collection with a better shard key. For choosing a proper shard key, please read [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) in the MongoDB docs.

P.S. I wasn't sure wether to answer this question, since it is slightly off topic on Stackoverflow, which is aimed at programming questions. But since usually the developers are supposed to choose the shard key, my intention was to clarify things for them. Additionally, the data modeling might be influenced by sharding considerations, so – by a small margin – I thought it was ok to answer here. However, dear reviewer, feel free to flag this answer for deletion if you think differently. I am really not sure.